# How do I evalute the value of an given only the radii of 2 spheres??

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, spherical-coordinates

[image]

The question basically. I was able to find rho and theta $rho$ and $theta$ as $\int_1^5\int_0^2pi$,(2pi is the top limit), respectivley. I can't find $phi$ though and I'm assuming thats wrong. My integrand is $\rho^3\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi) \,d\rho d\theta d\phi$ Can anyone help me go into the right direction? I don't know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are so very close.  Your integrand is correct, your Jacobian is correct, and your limits of integration for $\rho$ and $\theta$ are correct.  The only thing you are missing is the limits for $\phi$.

To figure this part out, you need to think about how $z$ is parametrized in the spherical coordinate system.  You did not explicitly specify a parametrization, but one that works and is consistent with your integrand is
$$\begin{align} x &= \rho \cos \theta \sin \phi \\ y &= \rho \sin \theta \sin \phi \\
z &= \rho \cos \phi, \end{align} \tag{1}$$

in which $\rho$ is the distance of $(x,y,z)$ from the origin, $\theta$ is the counterclockwise angle of the point $(x,y,0)$ measured from the positive $x$-axis, and $\phi$ is the angle that the $(x,y,z)$ makes with the positive $z$-axis--so we have $\phi \in [0, \pi]$ and $\phi = \pi/2$ will give $z = 0$, which is the "equator."

With this in mind, it is clear that the upper hemisphere will correspond to the interval $\phi \in [0, \pi/2]$.  So this is your limits of integration for $\phi$, and the desired volume is
$$V = \iiint_D z \, dV = \int_{\rho=1}^5 \int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} \int_{\phi = 0}^{\pi/2} (\rho \cos \phi) \rho^2 \sin \phi \, d\phi \, d\theta \, d\rho, \tag{2}$$
which I leave you to evaluate.

One comment I have about this problem is that I find its phrasing imprecise.  "The spheres of radiuses (sic) 1 and 5" is totally vague, since we are apparently expected to assume that these spheres are *centered at the origin*.  Less problematic but still vague is the phrase "between the spheres...." A more precise statement would be to say something like "outside the unit sphere but inside the sphere of radius $5$ centered at the origin."  Or more explicitly, one could have given a system of inequalities; e.g.,

> Compute $$\iiint_D z \, dV$$ where $$D = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : (z \ge 0) \cap (1 \le x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 25) \}.$$

Comment: I got 156pi as the answer, but it seems to be wrong.

Comment: @James $156 \pi$ should be the correct answer, assuming that my interpretation of the question is correct.  In the screenshot of the question, it shows $156\pi$.  Is that what you typed into the answer box, or is that the provided answer?

Comment: Its the answer I initially got because I also got 0 to pi/2 for phi.

Comment: @James Unfortunately, I can't help you further; that is the answer I got as well.  I even performed the calculation in Cartesian coordinates and got the same result.

Comment: Ah ok. This is hopefully a glitch or something. Thanks for your help man.